# find $\det(\det(A)B[\det(B)A^{-1}])$

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

$A$ and $B$ are matrices, let
$A= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 3\\-1 & -2 & 1\\2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 1\\-1 & 1 & 1/3\end{bmatrix}$ find the next: $$\det\left(\det\left(A\right)B\left[\det\left(B\right)A^{-1}\right]\right)$$

Comment: Do you remember how $\det(A)$ and $\det(kA)$ are related, for matrix $A$ and scalar $k$? Do the square brackets have any significance, considering you mostly grouped with parentheses?

Comment: This question  has nothing to do with the actual values in $A$ and $B$. By linearity, the answer is $\;( \det A)^2(\det B)^4)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, for two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of order $n$, $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$. Therefore, for any given scalar value $k$, $$\det(kA) =\det(kIA) = \det(kI)\det(A)= k^n\det(A).$$

Utilizing the two properties,
$$\det\left(\det(A)\;B\;\det(B)\; A^{-1}\right) = \det(A)^3\det(B)^3\det(BA^{-1})$$
$$=\det(A)^3\det(B)^3\det(B) \det(A^{-1}) = \det(A)^2\det(B)^4 = 8^2\frac{1}{3^4} = \frac{64}{81}$$

Remember that $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ are scalar values, hence we are able to use the property mentioned earlier.

Comment: how do you get det(A)^3det(B)^3 ???

Comment: @shuuichi_nitori I had added some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: @TenailRaman thank you very much, and forgive my poor comprehension, I was asking about the determinant to the third power, why to the 3rd power??

Comment: @shuuichi_nitori Because A and B are square matrices of order 3.

Comment: Oh that's right, thank you very much!